# Materialized modal not displaying

Tags: jquery, html, css, modal-dialog, materialize

I follow/copied all the content available [here](http://materializecss.com/modals.html#structure). But when the time I click the link button, the gray background(overlay) display, but the modal itself was missing.

---

Behavior in different browsers:

**Chrome 53.0** overlay display, modal did not display

**Mozilla 18.0, IE 11.0, Opera 42.0** overlay display, modal display for less than a second then fades away

---

Checking the Developer tool / Developer menu / Developer toolbar indicates that the modal should be visible.
Here are the tags for reference:

**Button link** *removed the class in sample to maintain the link design*

```
<a href="#modal1">Modal</a>
```

**Modal on page load**

```
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
<!-- contents same with the sample located at http://materializecss.com/modals.html#structure -->
</div>
```

**Modal on button link clicked** *When hover, highlight on screen was also not visible*

```
<div id="modal1" class="modal open" style="z-index: 1003; display: block; opacity: 1; transform: scaleX(1); top: 10%;">
```

**Modal on close**

```
<div id="modal1" class="modal" style="z-index: 1003; display: none; opacity: 0; transform: scaleX(0.7); top: 100px;">
```

**Overlay on button link clicked**

```
<div class="modal-overlay" id="materialize-modal-overlay-1" style="z-index: 1002; display: block; opacity: 0.5;"></div>
```

**Script to initialize** *located at the end of body element*

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.modal').modal();
    });
</script>
```

---

How will I fix this? Are there any way to know what's the problem?

---

**Here's the HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title><!-- title --></title>
    <link href="favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript_path/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript_path/jquery-ui-1.8.24.js"></script>
    <link href="css_path/materialize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css_path/material.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="grey darken-3 white-text" role="navigation">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
            <a href="#" class="brand-logo" />
            <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="menu"></i></a>
            <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" data-activates="dropdown_more_main_menu" class="dropdown-button" id="dropdown-more-main-menu"><i class="more_vert"></i></a>
                    <ul id='dropdown_more_main_menu' class='dropdown-content'>
                        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li>
                            <!-- HERES THE MODAL NOT WORKING -->
                            <!-- HERES THE MODAL NOT WORKING -->
                            <a href="#modal1">Logout</a>
                            <div id="modal1" class="modal">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <h4>Logging out</h4>
                                    <p>Are you sure you wish to logout?</p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <a href="#" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Continue</a>
                                    <a href="#" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-red btn-flat">Cancel</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <!-- HERES THE MODAL NOT WORKING -->
                            <!-- HERES THE MODAL NOT WORKING -->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <!-- some contents -->
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript_path/materialize.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.modal').modal();
            // some codes
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you add `jQuery` to js lib?

Comment: yes. `JQuery 3.1.1`

Comment: Could you provide your full HTML code? I've tested with codepen but I work like example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

Move the `modal` outside the `navbar` and it's will display correctly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.modal').modal();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

<nav class="grey darken-3 white-text" role="navigation">
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="brand-logo" />
    <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="menu"></i></a>
    <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Profile</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" data-activates="dropdown_more_main_menu" class="dropdown-button" id="dropdown-more-main-menu"><i class="more_vert"></i></a>
        <ul id='dropdown_more_main_menu' class='dropdown-content'>
          <li><a href="#">Settings</a>
          </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li>

            <a href="#modal1">Logout</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
      <li><a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Profile</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Settings</a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="#">Logout</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <!-- some contents -->
</div>
 <!-- HERES THE MODAL WORKING -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Logging out</h4>
    <p>Are you sure you wish to logout?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Continue</a>
    <a href="#" class=" modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-red btn-flat">Cancel</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

I don't see any problem with demo code. Please check the snippet, maybe you missing some libraries?

If you use `cdn`, make sure all libraries loaded successfully.

Or you should check your import order of libraries. Ex, `jQuery` must be loaded before `materialize`

Comment: `JQuery` was imported on the `<head>` while `Materialize` was imported at the end of the `<body>`. Could this be a problem?

Comment: The problem not come from library. It's because you push `<div id="modal1" class="modal">` inside `navbar`, just move outside the `navbar`  and modal display correctly.

Comment: Nice, it work. Thanks. I wonder why this should be outside `navbar`, Was there a reason behind it?

Comment: Yes, It's because after click, the `ul` component which hold your modal change to `display:none` => All children component cannot display. One more point, your screen change to gray because Materialize add a div `.modal-overlay` in the end of document.